# Application to automatically search lyrics and store them in ID3-tags

Tags: software-recommendation, id3

I'm looking for an application that automatically searches lyrics on the internet and stores them in ID3-tags. Such a program, called [iArt](http://www.ipodsoft.com/site/pmwiki.php?n=IArt.HomePage), already exists for Microsoft Windows. Does a similar application exist for Ubuntu as well?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python script that will search for lyrics and embed those lyrics to your mp3 files.
[Script Blog](http://yask007.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/auto-mp3-lyrics-downloader-and-tagger-my-new-hack/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: `[user@ub Auto-MP3-Lyrics-Tagger]$ sudo pip install eyed3`

`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): eyed3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

`Cleaning up...`

`[user@ub Auto-MP3-Lyrics-Tagger]$ python auto_lyrics_tagger.py`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "auto_lyrics_tagger.py", line 4, in <module>`

`import eyed3`

`ImportError: No module named eyed3`

Comment: That error occurred because `eyed3` module wasn't detected.There is currently an issue with eyed3 installation , you should type

`sudo pip install . --allow-external eyed3 --allow-unverified eyed3` to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no application that will actually **automatically** write the lyrics to the iD3 tag for the file but rhythymbox has a plugin that will download lyrics from the internet.

Also remember that not all lyrics are available and subject to copyright in many countries.

There are many applications that will however enable you to edit the iD3 tags of your files either individually or in a batch;

- [Easytag](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) which is available in the software centre for installation.
- [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) which is available in the software centre for installation.
- [MP3 Diags](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/) which is a very feature rich and easy to use.
- [Puddletag](http://puddletag.sourceforge.net/) simple basic application.

Comment: Only a few iD3 editor applications are capable of editing lyrics tag. In instance, KiD3 can edit lyrics tag and Easytag not.

Comment: Amarok 1.4 has an script that let to read and save lyrics to iD3. Amarok 2.x doesn't have any script alike.

Answer (score 0):

[MediaHuman's Lyrics Finder](https://www.mediahuman.com/en2/). It does one thing, perfectly, free. Enjoy.