# Lyrics on mp3 ID-tag

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, mp3, tag, lyrics

Since a few years ago I stopped listening to CDs and began to listen to mp3 only. At the begining I continued to buy the CDs to support the artist, but later I started to buy the album direct online as mp3. The problem is, that by this, I don't have the lyrics for the songs. For the "commercial" or popular music it is not a big problem, but for others there are no lyrics on the Internet.

How can I make use of the ID3-tag for the lyrics? Is there a music store that adds lyrics to the mp3 files sold? Can this be done with Ubuntu One? Another alternative would be to have an Internet lyrics databases like musixmatch.com supported.

Comment: What music player do you use? There might be a lyrics plugin.

Comment: On Ubuntu I use Rthmbox, with a plugin for lyrics. On Android the player from musicmath, but with both without any lyrics. The question was not, how can I find one, but more, why Ubuntu Music Store don´t publish the lyric with the mp3.

Comment: Are you using the default lyrics plugin or a third-party lyrics plugin such as one from my PPA? http://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom, I'm now using the plugins from you ppa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fetch lyrics for all my music and store them within the files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/460932/how-can-i-fetch-lyrics-for-all-my-music-and-store-them-within-the-files)

Answer (score 1):

In case our mp3 files are not already tagged with lyrics (which is the usual case unfortunately) there are several other approaches to have access to lyrics while listening to mp3 music:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)
  By installing a third party plugin for rhythmbox you will be able to have online access to lyrics from sources other than with the default plugin shipped with Rhythmbox.
- [Need a MP3 ID3 tagger, and cover fetcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16036/need-a-mp3-id3-tagger-and-cover-fetcher)
  [Application to automatically search lyrics and store them in ID3-tags](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117458/application-to-automatically-search-lyrics-and-store-them-in-id3-tags)
  Some ID3 tag editors are able to also store lyrics in the tags. This - to my knowledge - can not be done automatically.
- [What media (music and video) players are there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there)
  Choose a media player capable of editing tags to also store lyrics. We have good experience with [guayadeque](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guayadeque) [image: Install guayadeque], a media player that comes with a tag **and** lyrics editor. This can be set up to search from several or custom lyrics sources from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this [script](http://yask007.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/auto-mp3-lyrics-downloader-and-tagger-my-new-hack/) for Auto Tagging Lyrics in mp3 files